# How to put a block of code between [shortcode][/shortcode] in do_shortcode()?

Tags: loop, shortcode

So I want to put a loop of post behind a 'like lock' thats created by a plugin that uses the shortcode [to_like ID="XX"]content[/to_like]. But instead of the plugin blocking the content, i just get a page with all the permalinks to the post on it.

So I guess what Im asking is how do I put the page contents (ie, the loop in the template that displays the post) inside the shortcode so its hidden by the plugin?

This is what Ive got right now:

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); 
    $content  = '<li><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">';
    $content .= '<span itemprop="name"><a href="'.the_permalink().'" tilte="'.the_title().'">'.the_title().'</a></span>';
    $content .= '<span itemprop="description"></span>';
    $content .= '<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">';

            $schemaStreet = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'schemaStreet', $single );
            $schemaCity = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'schemaCity', $single ); 
            $schemaState = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'schemaState', $single );

    $content .= '<span itemprop="streetAddress">'.$schemaStreet[0].'</span>';
    $content .= '<br /><span itemprop="addressLocality">'.$schemaCity[0].'</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">'.$schemaState[0].'</span>';

    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</li>';

    do_shortcode('[to_like id="1208"]'.$content.'[/to_like]');

endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Can you use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: Please follow up on your old questions answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with output is because you are using versions of template tags that immediately output the result when called, rather than return it to be concatenated with the string.

For example [`the_permalink()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_permalink/) as opposed to [`get_permalink()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_permalink/).